# Android programatic button font size in pixels

Tags: android, button

Is it possible to set programatically a font size (in pixels) for the text in a button, without using xml styles? Using Html.fromHtml(..) with font size=".." didn't worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`Button.setTextSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29) *(since the button class extends a simple TextView)*:

```
// Set textsize to 20px here
button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20);
```

Note though that it is **not** recommended to use pixels as a dimension at all, rather use *sp* when working with font sizes. Otherwise you will run into display problems on many devices due to the many different screens out there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try setTextSize() (Button inherits from TextView)

[TextView.setTextSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29)